# Why is it “des Lesens” instead of “der Lesen” for the Genitiv of Lesen

Tags: grammar, gender, genitive

It seems that *Lese* is a feminine word. However, its genetive (plural) seems to be *des Lesens* instead of *der Lesen*. I’ve read in my grammar book that for feminine words the Genitive should be in the form of *der alten Tanten*. So has my grammar book made a mistake? Or is it I got the example wrong. Or is there some exception to this rule?

Comment: The seemingly unrelated words reflect the etymology from Latin legere, "collect" and "read". We "pick up" words and grapes. Both can be a joy when fermented ;-).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems you mixed up several concepts.

1. There is a feminine word *die Lese* (meaning *the process of collecting*, usually grapes for making wine). Its genitive plural is indeed *der Lesen*.
2. There is a neutral word *das Lesen* (meaning *the act of reading*, sometimes also *the act of collecting*), the nominalized infinitive of *lesen*. It does not have a plural.
3. *Des Lesens* is the genitive **singular** of *das Lesen*.

Comment: Cool. I searched for Apple's dictionary for Lese, and it seems the only match is die Lese for some reason

Comment: @Xiang Ji: The dictionary will likely have an entry for the verb _lesen_ at least. Derived forms aren't usually given separate entries.

Comment: It took me up to your answer to remember that *Lese* is, in fact, a German word, too. I was so stuck on OP meaning *das Lesen* that I forgot about the first step of wine-making … and that with my parents coming from the largest wine-growing region in Germany ^^'